# Is the expression « hurler avec les loups » archaic?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

In my Oxford-Hachette dictionary they have the expression « hurler avec les loups » to mean "to follow the crowd". To me, this expression seems to be one of those ones which everyone understands but no-one uses (like the English expression "a bird in the hand is worth two in the bush"). So I was just wondering if anyone says this is real life anymore and if not, what are some more current ways I could say something similar?

Comment: I use the bird one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's rare, but I wouldn't say it's archaic.

I even found it in a video game forum:

> *D3 a su moderniser le H&S sur de nombreux aspects mais ya toujours les mêmes mecs qui **hurlent avec les loups** pour ne pas le voir et cracher dans la soupe.* [Source](https://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/42-36-68081761-5-0-1-0-la-beta-de-lost-ark-arrive-demain.htm).

Comment: Chroniqueuse TV et mariée au patron de Facebook France, donc deux fois au fait de la com' moderne: [Je n’aime pas hurler avec les loups](https://teleobs.nouvelobs.com/actualites/20160126.OBS3363/caroline-roux-je-n-aime-pas-hurler-avec-les-loups.html).